# Why not hold the last node pointer in LinkedList to reduce insertion at ending time?

Tags: data-structures, linked-list

Textbooks say that it takes O(n) for linked lists to insert at end because we only keep a pointer to the start node, and we'd have to traverse to the last node from the beginning. But why not just also store the last node pointer by updating every time we insert a new item in the linked list? Is it something defined in the design of linked list?

Comment: very good idea. this is exactly what you should do if you have more than a handful of insertions at end (or appendings of two linked lists). A "head" pointer of course needs to be maintained as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is the exactly things what some standard libraries have done. For example, in STL (C++) `std::list`, it costs constant time to append an element at the end of the list or to access the last element . Refer to [std::list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list) for some detail, although `std::list` in STL is double linked list.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a trailing pointer, but it depends on if the linked list is in order or not.  If you have a sorted linked list, you have to keep a pointer for the top of the linked list because you may need to insert an item there.  It's not necessary to have a trailing pointer in a sorted linked list, but it can help.  As far as the big-O notation for a linked list, you can have cases where the first element is what is being looked for, the best case would be O(1), however, the average case and worst case for a linked list would be O(n)